# Interpolation and approximation from Numerical Methods

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, approximation, interpolation

I was reading about **interpolation and approximation in Numerical Methods** and came across this statement in my course material, "for n data points, there is one and only one polynomial of order (n − 1) that passes through all the points" for example, we have 3 data points on a straight line then how can a second order polynomial satisfy it?

Comment: If they form a straight line, the second order polynomial will be 
$$
y= 0\cdot x^2  + bx + c
$$ with some constants $b,c$. But as soon as you start moving the points around a bit more, the first coefficient will become nonzero.

Comment: Well observed !

Answer (score 1):

The statement could be rephrased with "of order at most $n-1$" or "with possibly zero coefficients". What matters is that these polynomials have exactly $n$ degrees of freedom, and more importantly, that Lagrangian interpolation is always *possible* and *unique*.

For completeness, the text might also specify $n$ data points "with different abscissas".